# Is there a list of all magento 2 functions like getName(), getPrice() etc

Tags: magento-2.1

I'm trying to fetch information of certain products, just not sure what function is available.
I was wondering if there is a list of all magento 2 functions, like **getName()**, **getPrice()** etc.., then I can choose which I can use easily. thanks

Comment: I don't think there is.Because i have also search for this on Google but found Nothing.Its very important a complete list of functions with their details in Magento 2.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/135340)

Answer (score 2):

All Magento Models extend the `\Magento\Framework\DataObject` class. This class has the magic method `__call` implemented.

Long story short, it means that models don't necessarily have to have all the methods defined. Every column's **getter** and **setter** is already defined in the model. So for example, if there's a model `Phone` defined for a table `my_phones` having columns `phone_id`, `model`, and `price`, then the `Phone` class would have functions `getPhoneId()`, `getModel()`, `getPrice()`, `setPhoneId($id)`, `setModel($model)`, and `setPrice($price)` functions predefined, without us explicity defining it (notice the snake_case to CamelCase transformation while forming the method names).

This becomes more complicated when we deal with **EAV models** (like the Product model), since we don't know all the "columns" that it's fetching.

For an **EAV collection**, we can use the `addFieldToSelect()` method to add "columns" to retrieve.

And for models, we can always call the `getData()` method to fetch all the  data values.

So to answer your question, no there isn't any list of methods, because even Magento doesn't know all the methods required, since the admin can add new attributes later on. Still to get all the columns fetched, we could do something like `print_r(array_keys($product->getData()));` to print all the columns in the screen, for that model

Answer (score 1):

Its unclear to me what you are asking for If you want to know what a product model functions are available to use you can refer to

```
<Magento Dir>/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php
```

See in [Git](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product.php)